# Dart/Flutter: Use a 'final' variable, that is loaded asynchronously

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, dart-async

I am running into an issue regading using a final variable that is still loaded in asynchronously still after initializing, hence throwing a 'Re-initializing Exception'. The problem is that I am initializing a **final** instance of `class A` inside of `class B`. But the `classA`'s contructor seems to be doing some async work as well. As a result (seems to be the case after debugging), that the required arguments of `classA` are the only ones initialized when the instance is created. And when the rest of attributes of `classA` are initialized async, it tries remodifying the instance, throwing an Exception. The skeleton looks like:

```java
class classA {
  _mainAttribute;
  _otherAttributes . . .;

  //getters . . .

  classA (this.mainAttribute) {
    // async call
    _waitForJsonParse().then((_jsonRoot) {
      // initialize _otherAttributes;
    }
  }

  Future _waitForJsonParse() async {
    return await . . .;
  }
}

class classB {
  late final List<classA> _errorCausingAttr;
  
  classB () {
    // another async call
    _loadAssetManifest().then((manifestMap) {
      _errorCausingAttr = List.unmodifiable(
          mainfestMap.getFolders()
          .map((String folderName) => classA(folderName.someValue())
      );
      // Exception occurs here: "LateInitializationError:
      //Field '_errorCausingAttr@33137322' has already been initialized.".
    }
  }

  Future _loadAssetManifest() async {
    return await . . .;
  }
}
```

My first solution was to not use 'final' variables then. But is there a way to do it without sacrficing the kind of declaritive schemes? Maybe there is a better pattern / there is a code smell here?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  If `_errorCausingAttr` is assigned only via the `Future.then` callback registered in the constructor, I don't see how it's possible to trigger the "has already been initialized" error message, which indicates that it's been initialized twice.  That said, asynchronous initialization of a `late` variable is typically a bad idea anyway since you would not be able to prevent other code from reading that variable prematurely without adding and maintaining an extra flag.

Comment: If possible, I'd avoid using `late` by unconditionally initializing `_errorCausingAttr` to an empty `List` and then asynchronously mutating it.  If you're using `List.unmodifiable` to prevent mutation from external code, you could use modifiable `List` internally but return an [`UnmodifiableListView`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) to callers.